# Secure Terminal Services over the web

Tags: windows-terminal-services

I'd need to make Terminal Services available over the web, what is the best (secure) way for me to do this?

Thanks
S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'd employ a secured connection such as a VPN of some sort (OpenVPN, PPTP, Cisco, ssh-tunneling, etc).

As long as you're running RDP v6 or higher, the connection is encrypted - but authentication may not be (if I understand the documentation properly).

Comment: It is as encrypted as the connection, but not more so.

Comment: before v6 it was completely unencrypted (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol). With v6, I do not know if you can turn it off.

Comment: There is also a significant man-in-the-middle attack vector, which is why additional security is reccomended.

Comment: that was addressed with the update to v6, from my understanding

Answer (score 2):

Look into the Remote Desktop Gateway service (present in Windows 2008 and higher) - it will tunnel RDP traffic inside a SSL stream, abstracting the terminal server from the client. Much the same way that Citrix Secure Gateway did.

Answer (score 0):

[Citrix Access Gateway](http://www.citrix.com/English/ps2/products/product.asp?contentID=15005&ntref=prod_top) or a simple [ssh tunnel](http://www.bitvise.com/remote-desktop)